# Changing Scale of Notepad++ in Linux

Tags: scaling, notepad-plus-plus

I have a problem with the scaling Notepad++ in my Ubuntu since I have a 4K screen, and unfortunately, it is not displayed correctly. I was wondering if there is any way to scale up the menu and font of Notepad++ in Linux.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details, nor clue as to what package type you used to install notepad++

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop amd 64 on Vmware, and I installed Notepad++ with the command: sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  so you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  (20 is the specialist server products, Ubuntu Desktop releases are all *year.month* in format, ie. 20.04 is available as a desktop or server system, 20 is *headless* server only!)

Answer (score 0):

```
notepad-plus-plus.wine winecfg
```

Then change the dpi under "graphics" menu